# Direct all URLs to one page using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am learning about `.htaccess` and URL re-direction. I am trying to re-direct all of my website traffic to one document, but keep whatever URL was requested as the current URL.

For example, requests like:

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com/home
www.mydomain.com/about
```

all point to `www.mydomain.com/index.php` on my end, without changing what the user sees.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, that's what mod_rewrite is for. an internal-only rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

No `R` flag here will make sure that your URL in the browser stays while silently rewriting each URL to `/index.php`

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)